# How to resolve: Cannot determine the module for class OverlayPortal

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm facing following issue: If I try to build my Ionic 3 app for ios with the `--prod` flag, I get following error:

```
typescript error
Cannot determine the module for class OverlayPortal in
C:/.../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/overlay-portal.d.ts!
Add OverlayPortal to the NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class IonicApp in
C:/.../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/app-root.d.ts! 
Add IonicApp to the NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class ClickBlock in
C:/.../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/click-block.d.ts! 
Add ClickBlock to the NgModule to fix it.
```

Build command used:

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod
```

The error does not appear if I build without the `--prod` flag or if I use `ionic serve`. I'm not using any of the classes mentioned in the error message in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by searching through my code and removing any reference to Ionics `Page` class, which is suggested [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-determine-the-module-for-class-ionicapp-command-ionic-cordova-build-platform-prod-release-failure/110489/7).

Example: Turn `let page : Page;` into `let page;`

Also make sure to remove any imports of the `Page` class, which might look like this:

```
import { Page } from 'ionic-angular/umd/navigation/nav-util';
```