# Ionic 3 build failure - Cannot determine the module for class OverlayPortal

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Despite these answers to a very similar question none of the solution are working for me:

[How to resolve: Cannot determine the module for class OverlayPortal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982973/how-to-resolve-cannot-determine-the-module-for-class-overlayportal)

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues

The build is working fine when running `ionic build` however `ionic-build --prod` when AOT etc is required there are issues.

This is the full error:

```
[16:52:25]  typescript error 
            Cannot determine the module for class OverlayPortal in /Users/xxxxxxx/Development/xxxxxxx/mobile/node_modules/ionic-angular/components/app/overlay-portal.d.ts! Add OverlayPortal to the NgModule 
            to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class IonicApp in /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Development/xxxxxxxx/mobile/node_modules/ionic-angular/components/app/app-root.d.ts! Add IonicApp to the NgModule to fix it. 
            Cannot determine the module for class ClickBlock in /Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/Development/xxxxxxxxxx/mobile/node_modules/ionic-angular/components/app/click-block.d.ts! Add ClickBlock to the NgModule to 
            fix it. 

[16:52:25]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[16:52:25]  Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above 
Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
    at /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Development/xxxxxxxx/mobile/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:237:55
    at step (/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Development/xxxxxxxxxx/mobile/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Development/xxxxxxxxxx/mobile/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/xxxxxxxx/Development/xxxxxxxxxx/mobile/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:4:58)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.
```

I've tried downgrading typescript < v3 however Capacitor doesn't like this. All imports have been checked for inconsistency, as advised, so remain a little stuck.

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599017/error-cannot-determine-the-module-for-class-overlayportal-in-prod/66583277#66583277